# React/Redux - Storing an item in state AND sending it to a database

Tags: mysql, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm building an application, and part of that application is that it allows people to favorite certain items. They just click the SVG heart icon, and it turns red, and it's stored to 'favorites' in state *and* it's sent to the database (MySQL).  If they click the icon again, it goes back to grey, it removes it from state, and it runs another fetch to the database to delete that item.

I've been trying to build this into my action creator, but I can't get them both to work (that is, I can't get it to send to state AND to the database).  I did, however, get it functioning perfectly for the state piece.  I'm putting that below:

```
export const toggleFavorite = name => (dispatch, getState) => {
  const { searchResults, favorites } = getState()
  const currentSelection = filter(
    selection => selection.name === name,
    searchResults
  )
  const newFavorite = contains(currentSelection, favorites)
    ? reject(equals(currentSelection), favorites)
    : append(currentSelection, favorites)
  dispatch({
    type: SET_FAVORITE,
    payload: newFavorite
  })
}
```

So, my question is this: where and how do I put my fetches to the back-end to allow inserting and deleting?  This was my last failed attempt:

```
export const toggleFavorite = name => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  const { searchResults, favorites } = getState()
  const currentSelection = filter(
    selection => selection.name === name,
    searchResults
  )
  const newFavorite = contains(currentSelection, favorites)
    ? reject(equals(currentSelection), favorites)
      await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/deletefavorite?user_id=1&selection_id=${currentSelection}`)
    : append(currentSelection, favorites)
      await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/addfavorite?user_id=1&selection_id=${currentSelection}`)

  dispatch({
    type: SET_FAVORITE,
    payload: newFavorite
  })
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should replace the ternary condition by a classic if/else :

```
if (contains(currentSelection, favorites)) {
    const newFavorite = reject(equals(currentSelection), favorites);
    await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/deletefavorite?user_id=1&selection_id=${currentSelection}`);
    dispatch({
        type: SET_FAVORITE,
        payload: newFavorite
    });
} else {
    const newFavorite = append(currentSelection, favorites)
    await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/addfavorite?user_id=1&selection_id=${currentSelection}`);
    dispatch({
        type: SET_FAVORITE,
        payload: newFavorite
    });
}
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect.  Worked like a charm.  Thank you so much for your help!